# Padding not being applied to string

Tags: c#, string

Hi I am just trying to add a zero to a number that is a string, for example, a company has some old barcodes in the system that was printed with only 12 characaters their new barcodes is 13 I just simply have to add an extra zero when its 12 in length.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string BarCode="000001661705"; 
         char pad = '0';
         if(BarCode.Length==12)
         {
            BarCode = BarCode.PadLeft(1, pad);       
         }
        Console.WriteLine("Length of barcode" + BarCode.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Barcode=" + BarCode);        
    }
}
```

Here is the .net fillddle you will see the number of characters is still 12 when it should be 13 with the added zero on it.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsvPIl

Comment: `totalWidth`: *"The number of characters in the resulting string, equal to the number of original characters plus any additional padding characters."*

Comment: what has total width got to do with it

Comment: `totalWidth` is the name of the first parameter of `PadLeft`. You're passing `1` and your input already exceeds that length.

Comment: I just want to pad a zero on at the start no matter how big the number is

Comment: `"0" + BarCode` will do that. `PadLeft` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: If you want a string with at least 13 characters then PadLeft(13, pad);

Comment: I was having a newbie moments folks

Comment: @rogue39nin Happens to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Just add it as a string?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string BarCode="000001661705";

             char pad = '0';
            if(BarCode.Length==12)
            {
                BarCode = pad + BarCode;


            }
        Console.WriteLine("Length of barcode" + BarCode.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Barcode=" + BarCode);

    }
}
```

Comment: I was having a neewbie moment

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `BarCode.PadLeft(BarCode.Length + 1, pad)` to get the desired output.
 But I don't understand why you would want to do that, just add `"0" + BarCode`

Answer (score 1):

`PadLeft` accepts as an argument `totalWidth` of returned string, so it pads if string is shorter and does nothing when length is already equal to o greater. Just use:

```
BarCode = BarCode.PadLeft(13, pad);
```

instead of

```
if(BarCode.Length==12)
{
  // here is the problem, you specified totalWidth = 1
  BarCode = BarCode.PadLeft(1, pad);       
}
```

[String.PadLeft Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8)